# Prevent exec command running on module unload ibm load sharing facilty

Tags: linux, tcl, redhat, lsf, modulefile

I have a tcl script which is a modulefile within the IBM Load Sharing Facitily (lsf) used to configure some environment variables and launch a python script by using the `exec` command.

When the module is unloaded normally the opposite of all the commands are run, but also the `exec` command is run as normal.  I would like it so that the `exec` part is only run on `module load` and not on `module unload`.

Here is what I tried so far

```
if { !(is-loaded mymodule)} {
    exec .venv/bin/python mypython.py
}
```

I also tried this

```
if { module-info command load } {
    exec .venv/bin/python mypython.py
}
```

For each one I get a similar error

```
Module ERROR: invalid bareword "module"
in expression " module-info command [load] ";
should be "$module" or "{module}" or "module(...)" or ...
```

both exceptions complain either about an invalid bareword (either "is" or "module") depending on which snippet I try.  Is my snytax invalid?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some code…

Comment: I added some sample code above.  I am not too familiarwith tcl or lsf, so was hoping there was just some easy check that I am not aware of, rather than a hand-crafted solution if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My syntax was incorrect, in the end I was able to solve the problem with the following:

```
set is_load_command [module-info command load]

if { $is_load_command == 1 } {
    exec .venv/bin/python mypython.py
}
```

I had two problems, correctly understanding comparisons in tcl and using return values from a called function.  Neither really behaved how I am used to.

Comment: if statement can also be written this way:

    `if { [module-info command load] } {`